# How to perform geospatial queries in mongoose on virtual field?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

In my collection `records` I have documents with such structure:

```js
@Schema()
export class Record {
  @Prop()
  title: string;

  @Prop()
  lat: number;

  @Prop()
  lon: number;
}
const RecordSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Record);
RecordSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' }); // <- must be a physical property i guess?
export { RecordSchema };
```

`lat` and `lon` fields are for the latitude and the longitude of the object respectively. I want to retrieve all `Record`s that are closer than `radius` metres from point with coordinates (`userLat`;`userLon`). However, I really do not want to store `Record`'s latitude and longitude in `location` field (like `{title: "test", location: {type: "Point", coordinates: [50, 80]}}`, though it works).

I created a virtual `location` on my schema:

```js
RecordSchema.virtual('location').get(function (this: RecordDocument) {
  return {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [this.lon, this.lat],
  };
});
```

And tried to query over it:

```js
async findAll(params: FindRecordsQueryParams): Promise<FindAllResultDto[]> {
  const { userLat, userLon, radius } = params;
  const aggregation: PipelineStage[] = [
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [userLon, userLat],
        },
        distanceField: 'distance',
        maxDistance: radius,
        spherical: true,
        key: 'location',
      },
    },
  ];
  return this.recordModel.aggregate(aggregation).exec();
}
```

However, this always returns empty list. So is there a way to perform a geospatial query over a virtual field or any other way to avoid storing `lat` and `lon` in GeoJSON Point format?